# Is it possible to have parameterized specs in RSpec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, rspec2, rspec3

If I have a spec that needs to be run with different values to have it drive a real implementation and not a naive one. An example:

```
it "should return 'fizz' for multiples of three" do  
  @fizzbuzz.get_value(3).should == "fizz"
end
```

So far I haven't found any way to pass 3 in as a parameter. The spec below solves my problem but I'm wondering if it's the recommended way to do it or if there is any other, better way.

```
it "should return 'fizz' for multiples of three" do  
  [3, 6].each{|number| @fizzbuzz.get_value(number).should == "fizz" }
end
```

I don't like this because it uses loops, it's not readable and it only shows up as one spec when run, I would rather have it show up as two different tests.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To generate separate tests you could do:

```
[3, 6].each do |num|
  it "should return 'fizz' for multiples of three (#{num})" do  
    @fizzbuzz.get_value(num).should == "fizz"
  end
end
```

Because spec files are simple run as ruby scripts you can use all the standard ruby constructs to generate tests on the fly.

Even better you can use [`Numeric#step`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Numeric.html#M000983) to easily generate a certain range of tests, e.g. for `[3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18]`:

```
3.step(18, 3) do |num|
  it "should return 'fizz' for multiples of three (#{num})" do  
    @fizzbuzz.get_value(num).should == "fizz"
  end
end
```

Comment: The humble `#each` technique is very effective! I made a small DSL to make parameterized testing with RSpec a bit more convenient: https://github.com/odlp/rspec-with_params (it allows multiple parameters, and prints out each group with a "given a => b, x => y, " context for clarity)